# How to plot xy coordinate graph in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-center, plot

I'm learning network and transportation model. I' d like to plot graph in xy coordinate from the following data:

[image]

I am familiar with R and LaTeX, but I don't know is there any easy to learn and easy to control software in Ubuntu that can help me plot xy graph in xy coordinate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want *simple*, you should probably just put your data into `LibreOffice Calc` and have it draw a plot.

If you want something you can customise more and script for repeated use, there are many choices, but since you say you know `R` this would be the obvious choice. Some others might be `python`+`matplotlib`, `octave`, `gnuplot`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have grace (xmgrace) and gnuplot which are common software.

xmgrace has got a graphical interface whereas gnuplot is a prompt where you enter some commands.

I think xmgrace (grace is the package name) is easier than gnuplot because of the graphical interface. The only drawback of xmgrace is that you cannot plot 3D graph.